# No exception received from Rake task with Airbrake rails integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, airbrake

Since version 5 Airbrake and its Rails integration offers automatic exception reporting in any Rake tasks.
However I've not received rake exception on my errbit server.

I've made the following test :

- Create a fresh rails 4.1 application.
- Include airbrake gem.
- Create Airbrake initializer (used an errbit configuration).
- Add a rake task which raises an exception.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'airbrake', '5.0.5'
```

**initializers/airbrake.rb**

```
Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.environment = Rails.env
  config.host = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/'
  config.project_id = true
  config.project_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
  config.ignore_environments = []
end
```

**lib/rake/raise.rake**

```
namespace :raise do
  desc 'raise error'
  task error: :environment do
    1 / 0
  end
end
```

I tried to execute the rake task `rake raise:error` and got the following backtrace:

```
rake aborted!
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
/Users/Yann/code/airbraker/lib/tasks/raise.rake:4:in `/'
/Users/Yann/code/airbraker/lib/tasks/raise.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Yann/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/airbrake-5.0.5/lib/airbrake/rake/task_ext.rb:19:in `execute'
Tasks: TOP => raise:error
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And never received any exception on my errbit server.

**Note:** execute `rake airbrake:test` sends an exception to my errbit server, I assume my configuration is correct.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What's your full backtrace when you raise it?

Comment: @kyrylo I added it . For information airbrake version is 5.0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a minor bug. The problem is that Airbrake tries to be asynchronous and sometimes it doesn't work as expected. In this particular case the Ruby process quits before Airbrake sends your exception.

I've submitted a patch, which should fix this issue: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/pull/513

Comment: I've applied you patch and it works fine. Thanks for PR and your time !